# SNI_PN11, error: 56 - Unable to load the SQLUserInstance.dll from the location specified in the registry

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, apple-m1, parallels

I'm new to ASP.NET and SQL, just trying to learn. I get the following error when I run `update-database` to create a database with EF.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 56 - Unable to load the SQLUserInstance.dll from the location specified in the registry. Verify that the Local Database Runtime feature of SQL Server Express is properly installed.)

Connection String:

> "ConnectionStrings": {
> "BethanysPieShopDbContextConnection": "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=BethanysPieShop8854;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
> }

I'm running Windows on Parallels on an M1 Ultra, so not sure if I'm just doing something stupid or if Arm64 is getting in my way. Has anyone else seen similar issues on Apple silicon?

Comment: Where is the SQL Server instance being hosted? I assume on a different host?

Comment: @Larnu just on my local machine

Comment: Add your connection string.  You really shouldn't be using user instances.  Instead use a normal SQL Server Express instance, or SQL Server Express LocalDb.

Comment: And what does `sqllocaldb i` print?  And install it or reinstall it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: That prints `MSSQLLocalDB`. I reinstalled SQL Server Express 2019 LocalDB via the Visual Studio installer and restarted the VM. No soup.

Comment: Is probably ARM64 related. Not authoritative, but... [Unable to load SQLUserInstance.dll from the location specified... #1752](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1752) _LocalDB is not fully supported on Windows11 ARM64 and there are other users having the same problem on Windows 11. This is not SqlClient issue. The SQLUserInstance.dll is installed while you install SQLLocalDB. To give more detail on this, the mentioned dll is made for x64 architecture, thus is not compatible on ARM 64._

Comment: @AlwaysLearning that looks like it. Thanks for the clarity!